# CORS Filter Stops working after some time

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cors

My Application is Angular Front-end with Spring Back-end. I am trying to access some Restful webservices from back-end to my front end. Here is the Angular Call I make to my Custom Http service:

```
stationFilter(stFilt : StationFilter): Observable<Response>
  {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post' });
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    // options.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token);
        }

    this.requestJsonBody = JSON.stringify({'snmpFlagOn': stFilt.snmpFLag, 'noIpStations': stFilt.noIPStation, 'stationDataDateBegin': stFilt.inputStartDate, 'stationDataDateEnd': stFilt.inputEndDate });
    console.log(this.requestJsonBody);
    return this.stationHttp.postService(this.confPropLoader.stationUrl + '/services/stationCollection/viewCollected', this.requestJsonBody, options);

}
```

For the Authorization above I am using JWT based token.
Here is my angular type-script based Custom StationHttp:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConnectionBackend, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request,
  RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class StationHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
      super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }


    getService(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.get( url, options).catch(this.handleError);
    }


    postService(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

        return super.post(url, body, options);

    }

}

export function customHttpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions): Http {
    return new StationHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
}
```

Following is the CORS filter written at Spring side:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.debug(" CORS Filter Running....");

        if (response == null) {
            LOG.debug(" Response is null");
        }
        LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
        // CORS "pre-flight" request
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-*, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-Type");
//      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        LOG.trace("Request:"+ request.toString());
        LOG.trace("Response:"+ response.toString());
        // }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The Restful services being called:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = { "/stationCollection" })
public class StationCollectionWS {
    @Autowired
    StationCollectionWSDBProcessing scWSDBPrcessing;

    @Autowired
    StationCollectionDAO stationCollectDao;

    @Autowired
    StationExpertStateBean stationExpertBean;

    @Autowired
    StationCollectionProperties stCollectProp;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "isClustered")
    Boolean isClustered;

    @RequestMapping(path = { "/viewCollected" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST }, consumes = {
            "application/xml", "application/json", "text/xml" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<StationCollectionData>> viewStationDataCollected(
            @RequestBody StationDataFilter filter) {

        try {
            log.debug("  View on the basis of filter:-> " + filter);
            Date startDate;
            Date endDate;
            List<Object> paramList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            StringBuilder sqlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(
                    "SELECT * FROM STATION_COLLECTION_DATA");

                /*
                    Do some processing for sqlStringBuilder here
                */
            String sql = sqlStringBuilder.toString();
            log.debug("Argument List:" + paramList);

            Object[] params = paramList.toArray();

             // Making DAO layer call
            RowMapper<StationCollectionData> stDataRowMapper = StationCollectionRowMappers
                    .getStationCollectionDataRowMapper();

            stData = (List<StationCollectionData>) stationCollectDao
                    .getRecords(sql, params, stDataRowMapper);



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<StationCollectionData>>(stData,
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = { "/submitRequest" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST }, consumes = {
            "application/xml", "application/json", "text/xml" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> submitStationCollectionRequest(
            @RequestBody Request request) {
        try {

            if (request.getProductType().trim() == null
                    || request.getProductIdentifier().trim() == null)
                return new ResponseEntity<>(
                        "Invalid Incoming Request. Please check the following values: [\' Product Identifier (SEID)\', \'Product Type\']",
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);


            String incmgProdType = request.getProductType();
            String incmgProdId = request.getProductIdentifier();

            if (incmgProdId != null && !incmgProdId.equals("")) {
                    if (!stationCollectDao.chekRecordExist(
                            "STATION_COLLECTION_QUEUE", "PRODUCTIDENTIFIER",
                            incmgProdId, true)) {
            if (scWSDBPrcessing.checkPrIdCollected(incmgProdId)) {
                            log.debug("Within Days Limit");
                            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                            responseHeaders.set("WithinLimit", "MyValue");
                            return new ResponseEntity<String>(
                                    "Requested Product Identifier:"
                                            + incmgProdId
                                            + " is within "
                                            + stCollectProp.getNoOfStationCollectionDays()
                                            + " days", responseHeaders,
                                    HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

             } 
             }
             }
             if(! incmgProdId.equals("ABC"){

                HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                responseHeaders.set("UnsupportedProductType", "MyValue");
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(
                        "Unsupported Product Type for Request",
                        responseHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

        } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {

            log.debug("Record Already Present In Queue");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("SucessfullyCompleted", "MyValue");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Successfully Submitted Record",
                responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Problem is For Some time I do receive requests (and the time is not predictable, sometimes its 8 hours, sometime its 12 hours) but after that, I start getting the following error:

[image: Error Message I recieve]

I see the pre-flight request passing successfully in network tab of chrome, as shown below:

[image: Pre-flight request]

But the Original request fails as  below:

[image]

The fact that it works for sometime, but afterwards it stops confuses me a lot. Am I missing anything?

Following is the Request Header for POST Call:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsInJvbGVz
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:137
Content-Type:application/json
Host:lqtremmt01.gl.avaya.com:9002
Origin:http://******************:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://******************:8080/stationUI/home/1001/station_filter
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

Adding the token I use:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.k1A8OXnA18YYL9aO_wY0j6DSQ29yHvN-ibeOzR6o9h8
```

That is an entire user detail which I get from Back-end Once Authorized. Once I fetch it, I save it in my session storage. Following is the code in Spring when I set the token in stUsr as below:

```
stUsr.setToken(Jwts.builder().setSubject(stUsr.getUsername())
                     .claim("roles",
                     userDb.get(stUsr.getRole())).setIssuedAt(Conversion.toDate(StationCollectionWSUtilities.getTodaysDate()))
                     .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "admin").compact());
```

This stUsr is what getting displayed in the token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162569/discussion-between-rahul-and-trichetriche).

Comment: It's hard to see in your screenshots, as you've cropped the request headers for the POST request, but it's not clear that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set in the actual request. We can see it in the response to the OPTIONS request, but are you certain that it's set in the POST request? Have you tried replicating the problem with a smaller example? For example, if you remove Angular from the equation and just use curl or PostMan or something to send the requests, do you see the same problem?

Comment: But if I might suggest something, maybe you should write `Authorization` and not `authorization` in your accepted headers header.

Comment: If I use RestClient, the request is working fine, Its just when I send request with my Angular UI I face this issue. I will Add/edit  the Request Header for post

Comment: I did that change as well from authorization to Authorization, the error still persists

Comment: And since your issue is time-related, are you sure your token is still valid ? With the wrong headers and/or the wrong error handling, you could be returning a 400 with a CORS error while it's just the Token that expired.

Comment: Please don`t remove angular tag unless you are 200% sure, as the request is working fine  with RestClient, but doesn`t work when called from my Angular Application.

Comment: Wrong Header and wrong error message is something I can double check, but the fact that It works for some time, sometimes for 12 hours somtimes for 8 hours, rules out the expiration of token.

Comment: as I told you, I am sure. If you issues are CORS related, this is a server issue. **But** if as I said, you did a wrong error handling, then your issue isn't about CORS, but still, it is server related.

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't rule that out, because it is still time-related. I'm pretty sure you're not trying to make the request every minute for 12 hours just to see for how long it works. But maybe you should ... This would give you the expiration of the token. Could you send me one of your tokens please ? Just post an edit with a token, or a comment

Comment: My token expiration time is Half an hour, how do you explain it to be working without any errors for 8/12 hours and then showing up this issue. Also with REST client I don`t face any problem

Comment: And why are you storing your token in your token ?!

Comment: storing token in token means??

Comment: It means that in your token, you have your token stored. Pretty self explanatory if you ask me. Your token holds a user named Tom Brady (great actor by the way), and your whole token. Why would you do that ?

Comment: In my first code, I parse the stored user from my sessionStorage and collect the token from there and set it to my code:  ' options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token); ' Is that the right approach??   this is how I set it to my Sesson User  'let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }'

Comment: This is the right approach. My issue is with your backend : in case you don't know, Tokens are built with a library, and contains 3 things : an header, a payload, and a signature. In your case, the token contains itself in the payload. Just copy-paste your token [on this website](https://jwt.io/) and you will understand.

Comment: Yes I did that, already and found that you are correct, however, I have updated the code above, which shows how I am creating the token using 'io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts' library. Also if you promise not to remove angular tag i`ll like to add it back

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. The issue for me was that my JWT expired and caused the Spring Boot application to throw an exception. The global exception handler responsible for sending the response back to the Angular application was done in a point in time when CORS headers had not been set.

To fix this issue I set the CORS response headers as the first thing in my doFilterInternal() method.

CORS response headers:

```
  httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-*");
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-*, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-Type");
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Hope it helps!